Play Asset Delivery size limit for install-time asset pack in 2024
I have an app using AAB and want to confirm size limit for install-time asset pack.
From https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859372#size_limits it says "Base module 200MB", and "Individual asset packs 1.5GB" for App download size limit.
So in my case it will be base app up to 200MB + 1 asset pack up to 1.5GB = up to 1.7GB total, is that correct? Because some older documents say up to 1GB install-time. Which is true in 2024?

Got an answer on Google Community Forums. Answer is yes, it's max 200MB base + 1.5GB for install-time.
